# Числа Рамануджана

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, дискретная-математика

Есть [известное число Рамануджана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_(%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)) - `1729`.  Это наименьшее число, выражаемое как сумма двух кубов двумя разными способами. Другими словами:
1729 = 1^3 + 12^3 = 9^3 + 10^3.

Какие есть еще числа Рамануджана, которые больше 1729? Можно как-то вычислить эти числа с помощью программы?
Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: Так какой был номер такси - 17291729 или 1729?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну, на питоне напишите сами, а на С++, чтоб найти такие числа до миллиарда примерно - вот такой простенький переборный код,

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<int,vector<pair<int,int>>> m;

int main()
{
    const int N = 1000;
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; ++i)
        for(int j = i; j <= N; ++j)
            m[i*i*i+j*j*j].emplace_back(i,j);

    for(const auto& [n,v]: m)
        if (v.size() > 1)
            cout << n << "  " << v.size() << endl;
}
```

который менее чем за полсекунды выкидывает [результат](https://ideone.com/zMm4kw) - список таких чисел. Дописать, если нужно, вывод самих возводимых в куб чисел - одна строка :)

Кстати говоря, эти числа - последовательность [A001235](https://oeis.org/A001235) в OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала возьмите перебор. 4 переменные 1 тождество если тождество верно то на печать иначе следующий. Определитесь с границами поиска и в бой

Comment: Спасибо. Сама уже об этом думала, решила спросить здесь, вдруг подскажут еще что-нибудь... 
Сейчас буду бороться)

Comment: Я думаю кратные решения тоже никто не отменял.

Comment: Зачем же - 4? Это сразу делает задачу куда более медленной...

Comment: Очень медленно и неэффективно.

Comment: Перебор никогда не был самым быстрым. Я этого не утверждал. Дело в том что програмно искать эти константы есть смысл один раз и пусть перебором. Нежели тратить время попросту.

Comment: Кстати он по памяти менее затратный нежели верное решение